# OpenGL Glass HUD?

Tags: windows, winapi, opengl, hud

Hello I Would like to know how to make somthing that looks like "Glass" the example would be in the game called Pikmin.

its in the HUD and i would like to know how to create somthing similar.
I Am not trying to copy the game i just like how it looks.

It looks like this: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_CWor6UdXxBk/SbaZDWSF6VI/AAAAAAAAFCU/UQgBvgGq-VE/s400/pikmin.jpg

The rectangles that have numbers in them

I Know how to create an HUD However i would like to know how to dynamicly genorate the background rectangles like in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [alpha blending](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transparency.htm) for drawing the bubbles. Assuming the reflections on them are static, all you need is a simple image. (If you aren't sure what the image should be like, look at a black wall in the game. The white parts you see should be what the red, green, blue AND alpha channels of the image look like.)

The numbers are just another set of alpha-blended images drawn on top (or below) the bubbles. The above goes for them too.

Comment: yes this is what i think too but i want to know how to create a texture like that ie what program or algrithm

Comment: That's outside the scope of this site, but get an image editor like GIMP or Photoshop, and on an empty (transparent) layer, make an ellipse selection, get a fuzzy circle brush and try painting just outside the selection.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they're just textures with alpha blending. One rectangular, one circular and then drawn and scaled to a polygon that fits whatever goes in them.